# Icon spacing in WIN 10

Tags: windows-10, icons

I have a problem where the icons have changed their spacing and are now very spaced out but are the same size. I have done some research to find the fix to this problem and came across someon else with the same problem but no fix. Here below I will post the pictures of the situation of my desktop view which is identical to the post by someone else on a different website :

[How desktop used to look (preferred)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uru1f.png)

[How desktop looks now (unwanted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhDFP.png)

How can I revert back to the old way that my desktop used to look. This is not a scaling problem. I think I want to change the size of the text displayed for the icons but im not sure if this is the problem.

EDIT: This has happened after I updated Windows

Comment: See if this helps>>>>>https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/increase-or-decrease-desktop-icon-spacing-windows-10/

Comment: @Moab I just stumbled upon this method but when I change the numbers the icons remain the same..

Answer (score 1):

While on the desktop, hold down the Ctrl key and scroll up and down using the wheel on your mouse.
When scrolling up, all the icons on the desktop increase in size.
When scrolling down, all the icons decrease in size.

Comment: This was the first thought that I had as well @Dark24.  Have some well deserved points!

Comment: Unfortunately did not fix my spacing problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method: Click on Desktop, hold Ctrl button while rolling the mouse wheel (or tap + or - key) forward and back to adjust icon size and spacing.

The harder method via editing the Registry:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16941-change-desktop-icon-spacing-windows-10-a.html

Always set a System Restore point first before editing registry:
http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/how-to-fix-windows-10-problems-with-system-restore-11364008291943